# Onion circuits on tails

Tags: tails, onion-routing

When I open onion circuits on tails the first column all have the same name, fingerprint, ip, is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called your [Guard](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/community/glossary) relay. With regular Tor, you can expect this relay to stay the same for a few months, but since Tails doesn't keep persistent state, I believe this should change every time you reboot the computer.